# $Recycle.Bin Appeared in Onedrive - How do I stop syncing nightmare?

Tags: sync, onedrive, recycle-bin

Onedrive is a pain, but for various reasons I'm stuck with it.

Sometimes it hammers my laptop HDD just scanning for changes. I figured it's deep nested directories that really does it in. A month ago I did a big cleanup and all was well, less hammering of the HDD etc.

### The appearance of "Recycle Bin"

This morning, HDD Hammer was back again. A folder titled "Recycle Bin" - Type "File Folder (.BIN)" had mysteriously appeared in Documents, and another one in Desktop (ruling out the possiblilty that I accidentally created one with a drag drop). This was the source of the 1000s of tiny folders and files.

On other computers that are sync'ed up, This folder appears as "$RECYCLE.BIN".

The `Onedrive - <<MY Org>>/Documents/Recycle Bin` has following properties

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Date created | October 2016 |
| Size | 5KB |
| Contains | >1000 files, >1000 directories |

All constituent files have an access date of 27/08/21 (Last friday when I used my laptop)
But the created date of the files is from before I even owned the laptop! What is going on?

Can I delete the folder without repercussions? And the other ones that have appeared in `Onedrive/Pictures` (9000 files)  etc. ?

I have files synced between 3 PCs. How can I find which was the source of these folders? Did I miss configure them?

### Responses to comments

I have not recently set up OneDrive. This has been setup for >6 years on one of the computers.

Yes it is actually backing up the $RECYCLE.BIN folder, regardless of whether it should or not.

[image]

But there is no directory junction going on!

```
C:\Users\...>dir "OneDrive - ...\Documents" /A:D
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 2EB0-....

 Directory of C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ...\Documents

31/08/2021  09:24    <DIR>          .
31/08/2021  09:24    <DIR>          ..
27/08/2021  15:52    <DIR>          $RECYCLE.BIN
27/08/2021  15:53    <DIR>          Audacity
```

### The continuing saga

I have discovered the option to back up the Documents, Desktop and Pictures folders.

It seems either my institution turned them on without me knowing, or I feel for the *strong hint* when setting up the new version.

Moving things `~/OneDrive - .../Documents/* => ~/Documents/*` just results in them being moved straight back again . I moved them into a `~/DocumentsTemp/*` in the mean time.
I can't currently disable the option as all I see is this "Another Application is using these folders. Close all OneDrive windows and try again":

[image: Another Application is using these folders. Close all OneDrive windows and try again]

I have managed to stop most of the 10,000s of files syncing by pausing storage and moving all the ones it automatically sync'd out. Resulting in yet more HDD Hammering:

[image: 10,000 files processing Onedrive]

Comment: Did I miss configure them?    .... I think so. I would keep OneDrive limited to a folder inside Desktop (which does not include Recycle Bin).

Comment: So never changed any configuration manually last friday, which is when this all started happening! Up till last week, these recycle bin folders haven't existed

Comment: That is a strange outcome, then. I am not sure why basic OneDrive would include the Recycle Bin. I will look around a bit.

Comment: When you setup OneDrive you likely choose the option to synchronize your desktop.  You also selected to synchronized the profiles Pictures folder.  As for the reason it’s synchronizing the Recycle Bin that is indeed strange but can probably be manually stopped by not synchronizing the Desktop

Comment: OneDrive can't backup `$Recycle.bin` unless manually configured to do so - check your `Documents` folder for a shortcut or junction to the partition's `$Recycle.bin`

Comment: Edited about these comments, thanks